# GLEW parameters completion in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, glew

Till now I've been developing OpenGL apps using GLEW in Visual Studio, but I recently switched to macOS and I'm trying out Xcode.

One very important thing to me is that I want the IDE to show me what parameters a function requires as I type it, and this worked fine on VS.
Unfortunately, GLEW defines OpenGL functions with the preprocessor command *#define*, and Xcode doesn't seem to handle that very well as it doesn't show me the parameter list for those functions.
For now I only found a couple of functions that work correctly and they are the *glBindTexture()*, *glBindTexture()* and *glDrawElements()* functions.

Is there a way to let Xcode now that the others( the *glBufferData()* function, for example) are also functions and that it should go retrieve the parameters list for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of GLEW is to provide you with function pointers to OpenGL functions.  However, on macOS this is not really necessary.  You can do something like this:

```
#if defined __APPLE__
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#else
// Or however you use GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>
#endif
```

This will not provide prototypes for anything newer than 4.1, however, so you would have to `#ifdef` those parts out.  Any functions which are not available at runtime will simply be `NULL`, which is basically the same way that GLEW works.

The other alternative is to use an OpenGL loader which provides a more IDE-friendly header.  These do exist, I think [glLoadGen](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home) is an example.

Comment: Thank you!
I'd rather not look into glLoadGen to avoid the risk of getting too confused for now :D
But I think including directly <OpenGL/gl3.h> will work splendidly, at least until I need more advanced functionalities.